# Unable to run my web application on the IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have to perform a batch job execution daily that takes 4 application configuration properties it starts to execute when my web app starts running on IIS server.I had previously created those application properties in web.config file. Aim was that user can edit the properties from front end which will also save the new values into web.config file and then restart the job process. However this runs successfully on my local machine but I get the following error at IIS server

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred
>   loading a configuration file: Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\s1xcl4vc.tmp' is denied.

I understand completely this is because of permission issues in IIS server and I don't want to modify anything at IIS else it can become a security issue.

However I am not allowed to touch the IIS server configurations. How can I execute the batch process on IIS server, then? (I want to do sth like reading and editing Properties file in Java)

Comment: Why not write the values to a database instead of the config file?

Comment: It sounds like a good solution but is there any other way of doing this without interacting with database?